R: join values, not variables?
I have 5 versions of the same dataset i.e., all version have the same columns and rows, with the same names. However, they contain values for different cells so that only if I could combine all of them, could I get all the data.
Here is an example:
dataset1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "A", "NA", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset1) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "2", "4", "3", "NA", "A", "NA", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset2) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "A", "NA", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset3) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "NA", "2", "NA", "NA", "A", "NA", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset4) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset5 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "NA", "2", "NA", "2", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset5) = c("Patient", "Treatment")

I would like to combine these 5 datasets in a way so that whichever cells in dataset 1 that is NA is replaced with values from dataset 2, if those cells are valid, or if not from dataset 3, and so forth, so that the result would look like this for the example data:
dataset_complete <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "2", "4", "3", "2", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset_complete) = c("Patient", "Treatment")

Is there an automatic way to do this? I tried to read of on join transformations (https://r4ds.hadley.nz/joins.html), but was not able to find a solution.
Kind regards

Row 4 can be 2 or 4. What's the rule behind it?

FYI, the term "join" in data science-y topics is often referring to a "merge" of frames, perhaps dplyr::left_join or base::merge, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272 (and https://i.sstatic.net/oX5Jc.jpg, for some reason a moderator chose to delete the highest-upvoted answer, smh).

This can be done with a reduction. Since you mentioned r4ds, I'll use dplyr::coalesce to handle replacing the NA values.
Up front, though, "NA" is a string literal, not R's NA. I'll assume you mean the latter.
dataset1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset1) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", "2", "4", "3", NA, "A", NA, "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset2) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "A", NA, "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset3) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset4 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", NA, "2", NA, NA, "A", NA, "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset4) = c("Patient", "Treatment")
dataset5 <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("1", "1", NA, "2", NA, "2", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "B"), ncol = 2))
colnames(dataset5) = c("Patient", "Treatment")

Since you reference Hadley Wickham's R4DS, I'll suggest using dplyr::coalesce and purrr::map2_dfc for this, though they are not required, a base R version is easy too.
Now for the solution:
Reduce(function(prev, this) purrr::map2_dfc(prev, this, .f = dplyr::coalesce), 
       list(dataset1, dataset2, dataset3, dataset4, dataset5))
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   Patient Treatment
#   <chr>   <chr>    
# 1 1       A        
# 2 1       C        
# 3 2       B        
# 4 4       B        
# 5 3       A        
# 6 2       B        

The order of the frames is important. Once a "cell" is non-NA, anything after that will be ignored (which I think is the intent). If we reversed the order of frames, for instance, we get a slightly different result (in Patient):
Reduce(function(prev, this) purrr::map2_dfc(prev, this, .f = coalesce), list(dataset5, dataset4, dataset3, dataset2, dataset1))
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   Patient Treatment
#   <chr>   <chr>    
# 1 1       A        
# 2 1       C        
# 3 2       B        
# 4 2       B        
# 5 3       A        
# 6 2       B        


Unlist into a matrix, then use max.col to get the first column that does not contain the string "NA".
m <- mapply(unlist, mget(ls(pattern = "dataset")))
dataset_complete <- dataset1
dataset_complete[] <- m[cbind(1:nrow(m), max.col(m != "NA", "first"))]
dataset_complete
#>   Patient Treatment
#> 1       1         A
#> 2       1         C
#> 3       2         B
#> 4       4         B
#> 5       3         A
#> 6       2         B

If your "NA" strings are actually NA it would be:
dataset_complete[] <- m[cbind(1:nrow(m), max.col(!is.na(m), "first"))]

If performance is a concern at all, here's a benchmark. First the candidate functions:
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

f0 <- function(datasets) {
  # from @r2evans
  Reduce(\(prev, this) map2_dfc(prev, this, .f = coalesce), datasets)
}

f1 <- function(datasets) {
  m <- mapply(unlist, datasets)
  datasets[[1]][] <- m[cbind(1:nrow(m), max.col(!is.na(m), "first"))]
  datasets[[1]]
}

f2 <- function(datasets) {
  Reduce(\(x, y) {x[idx] <- y[idx <- is.na(x)]; x}, datasets)
}

f3 <- function(datasets) {
  for (x in datasets[-1]) datasets[[1]][idx] <- x[idx <- is.na(datasets[[1]])]
  datasets[[1]]
}

Benchmark:
datasets <- mget(ls(pattern = "dataset"))

bench::mark(
  f0 = f0(datasets),
  f1 = f1(datasets),
  f2 = f2(datasets),
  f3 = f3(datasets),
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f0           12.6ms   13.5ms      73.2   128.9KB     9.15
#> 2 f1             77µs   85.7µs   10968.    103.3KB    19.5 
#> 3 f2            340µs  374.6µs    2565.     21.3KB    23.6 
#> 4 f3          337.3µs  370.7µs    2612.         0B    23.6

The max.col approach is fastest, and the for loop approach is the most memory-efficient.
